# Redis 2.8.12 slave sync failing

Tags: redis

I'm getting the following error when trying to sync from same version master in redis cloud:

```
# Server started, Redis version 2.8.12
* The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
* Connecting to MASTER pub-redis-99999.us-east-1-3.1.ec2.garantiadata.com:99999
* MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
* Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
* Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
* (Non critical) Master does not understand REPLCONF listening-port: -ERR wrong number of arguments for 'REPLCONF' command
* Partial resynchronization not possible (no cached master)
* Master does not support PSYNC or is in error state (reply: -ERR wrong number of arguments for 'PSYNC' command)
* Retrying with SYNC...
# MASTER aborted replication with an error: ERR unauthenticated session
```

I've definetly provided the right masterauth password so it must be something else.  Anyone seen this before?

Comment: What versions of Redis are your master and slave running?

Comment: As noted above, 2.8.12 for both.

Comment: Ahh, missed that.  What's in the master's redis log when this happens?

Answer (score 5):

So this is caused by Redis Labs blocking sync among other commands.  For details see https://redislabs.com/company/faqs#are-you-fully-compatible-with-open-source-redis.

Comment: SYNC is indeed disabled - please contact our help desk if you need any assistance.

Comment: Or just ask me here :)

Comment: @ItamarHaber so how do I replicate an instance?

Comment: There are several possible reasons for replication, some make sense while others don't in the context of a managed Redis service. For example, read scalability is handled by clustering in Redis Cloud and replication for HA is managed internally. What's the purpose of the replica that you want to set up?